# Measure the period of an unknown signal using TC1 in AVR (Assembly)

Tags: assembly, timer, counter, avr

I'm learning Assembly and I find the part of timer/counter quite confusing for me... In class, we had this example of period measurement using TC1 in AVR (metaAVR 328P):

> Use the TC1 to measure the period of an unknown signal. The period is known to be shorter than 128 ms. Assume that the clock frequency is 16 MHz. Use the number of clock cycles as the unit of the period.

The solution given to us was:

> Since the input-capture register is 16-bit, the longest period of the signal that can be measured with no prescaler is: 2^16 ÷ 16 MHz = 4.096 msec.
>
> To measure a period that is equal to 128 ms, we have two options:
>
> 1. Set the pre-scale factor to 1 and keep track of the number of times the timer counter overflows.
> 2. Set the pre-scale factor to 64 and do not keep track of the number of times the timer counter overflows.
>
> We will use the pre-scale factor of 64.

I get that the longest period that can be measured is 4.096 ms. But where do the two options come from? If we set the prescalor to 1, the clock frequency would be 16 MHz, so what happens? If then we set it to 64, the clock period would be 16MHz / 64 = 250 000 Hz = 250 KHz, then what happens? I just fail to see how setting the frequency relates to keep track of the number of times the timer counter overflows... Why do we need to to prescale the frequency anyway? Are we trying to find out the number of clock cycles, so

> ## clock cyles * clock frequency after prescaling = period?

Is the above equation right? At this point I feel like I'm confusing myself, so any hint would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

No, the equation is not right.

The frequency is the reciprocal of the time of one tick. At 16 Mhz, the tick is 1/16000000 of a second. That is why the 16-bit timer overflows after 65536/16000000 = 4096/100000 seconds.

The formula you are looking for is in units of seconds, so

ticks / frequency = period

will do.